# Change storage of globals in python

Tags: python, global

I'd like to change the storage of all globals in a python script, as if I could just write use_this_dict_for_globals(some_dict).

They're all prefixed with "g_" so if I could replace "g_" with "some_dict." to change all those variable accesses, this would work too. I'd actually prefer this way, but in Python I'd either need to use variable accesses like foo['bar'] and not foo.bar, or I need appearently some python class stuff (?) that I know nothing about.

Is there any quick/reliable way to do it?

**Update**: As all answers state, you can use a class instance like a dictionary, with no restrictions, foo.bar = 123. You just can't use this notation with dictionaries (like you can do in Lua with tables), which lead me to think there would be no way at all. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Python class stuff that I know nothing about"? Seriously, learn it. Even though Python is not a strict OO language, you won't get far without at least knowing the basics of OOP in Python.

Comment: Is `globals()` what you want? What do you mean by "they are all prefixed with g_"?

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman Ok, thanks for this unspecific but honest answer.

Comment: @ jadkik94 Is globals() = some_dict possible? I'll try, maybe it returns a reference to the globals to be changed. Tnx. In my script all the names of the global variables have the prefix "g_" is what I meant.

Comment: @ jadkik94 globals() = some_dict did not work. Well, actually I was thinking, I could later just exchange those "g_" prefixes with a "some_table." as you would do in Lua. But it seems to be not that easy.

Comment: @user1356442 You don't "replace" `g_` with `some_table.`. You create an object called some_table insctance of a class SomeClass and set its attributes. I don't know if that's what you meant by "replace", just to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this "python class stuff" to implement one object holding all your global variables. Note that I do not think that this is a good approach in general, but it comes very close to what you intended to do.

Near the beginning of your script, define a class `MyGlobals` and get an instance of it:

```
class MyGlobals(object):
    pass
g = MyGlobals()
```

You can access the object `g` at any point in your script like this:

```
g.foo = "foo"
print g.foo
```

But as noted in the comments, try to avoid global variables, and see whether you can make more use of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I would break out everything out into modules, and stay away from and thing global.

Have one module that has all of your global vars, and then pass an instance of this to other modules that need it.

```
class doSomeThing(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def some_func(self):
        # something
        pass

class Global_Config(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        # load global information

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # construct the config
    config = Global_Config(some params)
    one = doSomething(config)
    two = doSomethingTwo(config)
    # do stuff with do some work with one and two and config
```

Comment: Avoiding global state is cool, but don't fool yourself: If you pass it everywhere, it's still global. The only thing you gained is the *option* to pass something different, and you have to use that option or it's worthless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables in the global namespace named as `g_var1` and `g_var2` (very bad by the way), you can access them with:

```
some_dict = {varname[2:]: var for varname, var in globals().iteritems() if varname.startswith('g_')}
```

You will get a dict `some_dict` with all the global variables that start with `g_`. You can access these with `some_dict['var1']`.

But don't do this unless you absolutely have to. Use classes and modules/packages.
Simple example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'whatever'
        self.var2 = 'whatever also'

c = SomeClass()
print c.var1, c.var2
```

For more information, read about classes and modules (`import some_module` and stuff like that).

**Conclusion:**

Don't prefix with `g_` your global variables, use one dictionary in the global namespace and access these from there or your own class.

Good luck.

Comment: Aren't name prefixes irrelevant for this matter? I'd indeed like to use a global dictionary, but text editors usually provide no support for changing bar to foo['bar']. So a dot notation like foo.bar is what I prefer in general. But this notation/operator seems to preserved for the OOP part of Python only. Using OOP because of a storage class issue? I dislike this idea a bit. So in the end I'll have to use the foo['bar'] notation for the grouping of the variables. Thanks for your help though. Before I was not sure whether I need OOP for it, now I know.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. If it's just what you need a class for, then just define a class as such `class A(object): pass` and use `a_instance.var1 = something` to get what you want instead of a dict, and if you don't know what the variable name is (dynamic) you can use `setattr` and `getattr` on any object...

Comment: I've just read it again and see, that you mean, prefixing is a bad idea for bundling variables and accessing it like in the some_dict = ... code snippet.